# Why options are not available in EEGLAB menu options?

Tags: matlab, eeglab

I have such violet color for options which I would like to choose:

[image]

in all tutorials which I reviewed options which I'm trying to use like `From Neuroscal .EEG file` are black. But Neuroscanio is installed as I see for eeglab:

[image]

so is it possible to fix such problem?